Access denied even with the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
I'm trying to create an API server that has some endpoints that are accessible without authentication and some endpoints that requires authentication. I want to configure Spring Security to authenticate the user when possible, and still let the request through even when it cannot so that controller/service layer handle that.
Although I have some experience in Spring projects but new to configuring Spring Security, especially Spring Security 6 with Spring boot 3
I have my Spring Security configured like below:
// RestApiSecurityConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class RestApiSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain signInSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                         DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider) throws Exception {

        // This filter chain should be applied to all routes
        http.securityMatcher("/**")

                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        // All requests should be authenticated either with Basic or Anonymous Authentication
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())

                // Session is stateless
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))

                // Disable csrf and cors
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)

                // Enable BasicAuthenticationFilter with a custom DaoAuthenticationProvider
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider)

                // Add AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
                .anonymous(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

Expectation
My expectation is:

First try to authenticate the caller using BasicAuthenticationFilter
If the BasicAuthenticationFilter fails to authenticate, still attach some anonymous authentication object with AnonymousAuthenticationFilter and let the controller/service decide what to do

Since I have not set any authorization rule yet, the app should work the same way with or without the credentials.
Actual
If I put credentials in the header, the app works as expected. But if I don't put anything in the header the request fails with 401, before the request even reaches the controller.
2024-06-17T21:07:17.917-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@2129fad8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1bfb6db7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@49863271, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3dc1e968, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7e4949ac, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1decdf51, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@71008711, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2c76559e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4f6c6a90, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@47143ab9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3612b539, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2f113e31]] (1/1)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 DEBUG 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/posts
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Did not process authentication request since failed to find username and password in Basic Authorization header
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.918-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing GET /api/posts
2024-06-17T21:07:17.919-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on GET /api/posts using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@21795633
2024-06-17T21:07:17.922-07:00 TRACE 19168 --- [spring-template] [nio-4000-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0]

The authorization filter is blocking the request, but I'm not sure why it is blocking when there isn't any authorization rule in place.

.anyRequest().authenticated() you specified the rule that you can only login as an authenticated user. Anonymous isn't an authenticated user.


Since I have not set any authorization rule yet, the app should work the same way with or without the credentials.

Yes you have set authorization rules.
.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        // All requests should be authenticated either with Basic or Anonymous Authentication
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())

This piece in your security configuration are the authorization rules. The authorizeHttpRequests kind of gives that away.
You specified the rule to only allow authenticated users, anonymous is not an authenticated user, hence no access.
